# Access to composer autoloaded files in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, instance, bind, autoload

Trying to use a non-Laravel package: https://packagist.org/packages/luceos/on-app

Edited composer.json to require it and did the composer install, update, then dump-autoload -o.

This package requires an initialization: vendor/luceos/on-app/src/OnAppInit.php

Which isn't a class and only has the one method.  But it doesn't seem to be loaded when I try to bind it in a service provider.  The version for the cloud is initiated in the OnAppInit.php but that isn't being done so the "version isn't supported" error comes up of course.

I know that I am missing a small detail but can't find it.  Maybe in the service provider??

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "luceos/on-app": "~3.5"
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Luceos\\OnApp\\": "vendor/luceos/on-app/src/"
```

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    'App\Providers\OnAppServiceProvider',
```

app/Providers/OnAppServiceProvider.php

```
public function register()
    {
            $this->app->bind('onapp', function($app)
                {
                    $hostname = 'http://cloud';
                    $username = 'email@foo.com';
                    $password = 'api_key';
                    $factory = new \OnApp_Factory($hostname, $username, $password);
                    $setting = $factory->factory('Settings')->getList();
                    return $setting;
                });
    }
```

Looks like its there...
vendor/composer/autoload_files.php

```
$vendorDir . '/luceos/on-app/src/OnAppInit.php',
```

vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

```
'Luceos\\OnApp\\' => array($vendorDir . '/luceos/on-app/src'),
```

Comment: Using tinker I found the reason...  The OnApp cloud version isn't supported by the wrapper! Found out the cloud is version 2.3.3 and that is EOL according to OnApp.

Comment: Anybody know how to use Guzzle with Laravel 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the Guzzle question:
Just include it in your composer.json file:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"
```

And then just use the normal

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Just don't forget to to `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks for the guzzle hints. Used guzzle in a non-laravel project before so will have to dig up that client definition json again...

Comment: composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle" "~5.0"

composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: You don't have to use the -o flag for development – it's useful for production as it's shorthand for --optimize